# I want to update a DIV that will contain an image from a database PostgreSQL, without refreshing the entire page. Backend Django

Tags: django, postgresql, websocket, redis, django-channels

I want to update a DIV that will contain an image, initially there is no image, the image is in a database (the images table will have a field with the image path) PostgreSQL. Every time the database loads an image (it can be at any time) the DIV must be updated, showing the new image, without refreshing the HTML page. If the user wants to see the next image loaded in the database, he will only have to refresh the page. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @Ruby For that you must consider django-channels  library, to implement web-sockets in django.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution for you...

**USE AJAX**

Comment: Django Channel with Websocket and Redis, wouldn't that be the solution? I want it in real time, plus it will make millions of accesses to the server. Images are less than 1Mbyte. Thanks.

Comment: I can't say much about django channel because I don't know much about it at the moment.